# Unknown DataSource transport type 'json'

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

Every time I click my login button it's redirecting me to "https://www.themoviedb.org/authenticate/undefined

When it redirects I get this error in the console
Unknown DataSource transport type 'json'.
Verify that registration scripts for this type are included after Kendo UI on the page.

When I console log results i'm getting the token request it's just not adding to the url.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';


const movieApiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIEAPI;

class getRequestToken extends Component {

constructor(props) {

super(props)
this.state = {}


this.getToken()
}


 getToken() {

 console.log("Get request token from movieDB")

 const UrlString = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/authentication/token/new?api_key=" + movieApiKey
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: UrlString,
  success: (tokenResults) => {
      console.log("request token succesful")
      console.log(tokenResults);
      const results = tokenResults.request_token
      console.log(results)
  },
 error: (xhr, status, err) => {
      console.log("failed to get token")
      }
  })
 }


render() {
return (
  <div className="login">
    <a href={`https://www.themoviedb.org/authenticate/${this.results}`}>
      <button className="btn btn-outline-success" onClick={this.getToken} >Log In</button>
    </a>
  </div>
)
}

}
export default getRequestToken
```

Comment: I took a look at the API documentation and it looks like the request for a new authentication should use _GET_ and not _POST_. In your sample code there is a missing semicolon at the end of the `const UrlString = ` line. Can you confirm that the constant for `movieApiKey` is configured correctly?

Comment: I tried "GET" and it was giving me the same error. Also tried adding the semi-colon and didn't do anything. Yea my movieApiKey is configured correctly - I also tried it just using my actual API key instead of using my movieApiKey stored in my .env